# How to convert Windows-1255 To UTF-8 in Classic ASP?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, asp-classic, windows-1255

How can I convert a windows-1255 string to utf-8 in **classic** ASP?
My database is windows-1255 and I want to transfer my site to utf-8.

Answer (score 3):

Does the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916118/classic-asp-how-to-convert-string-to-utf8-to-usc2/920405#920405) do what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need to do any conversion.  Whilst your database may store the string in a particular encoding, ordinarily ADODB/OLEDB will deliver the string to VBScript/JScript running in a ASP page as unicode (since actually the script languages only support unicode its actually possible to have any other encoding).

Hence if your output needs to be UTF-8 you need to do this:-

```
 Response.Codepage = 65001 '' // or have a @codepage directive at the top of the page
 Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
 Response.Write sMyStringFromTheDatabase
```

If this doesn't appear to work for you then I suspect you've fallen foul of the Gotcha I describe in my answer that [Codebender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135138/codebender) has linked to.