# ASP connection to Oracle 10.2.0.5; Greek and Polish characters render with display problem

Tags: utf-8, asp-classic, oracle10g, connection-string

Working with an .asp application that connects and displays data cleanly.  Problem occurs with Greek and Polish characters. They render with 'upside down question mark'.  Running on IIS6 / Win2003.  I think Oracle 10.2.0.4 is installed.

It seems the code is using Response.CodePage = 65001  and Response.CharSet = UTF-8, e.g.:

```
<%
    Response.Buffer = false
    'Response.flush

    ' set up UTF-8 character set
    Response.ContentType = "text/html"  
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"  
        Response.CodePage = 65001  
        Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"  
%>
```

So far I've tried changing from:

```
'sConnectString = "PROVIDER=MSDAORA;" & _
```

to:

```
sConnectString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" & _
```

Using this OraOLEDB.Oracle Provider string allows Greek and Polish characters to display properly.  (changing the provider resolved)

Does this change from an MS Oracle driver (.dll?) to an Oracle driver (.dll?)
Why does this work?
How do I check what driver versions I have installed?

Any additional references or caveats you would recommend?  So far, reviewed:

[Using ASP to Internationalize Your Web Pages on Windows 2000](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742422.aspx#EBAA)

[Oracle forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9294813)

[Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127837/how-to-convert-windows-1255-to-utf-8-in-classic-asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what character set is your Oracle database?

The Microsoft Oracle Provider `MSDAORA` is very old, it was never updated since Oracle 7.0, it does not support Unicode. The `OraOLEDB.Oracle` is much newer. That explains why it works with the Oracle driver.

Comment: @user569090 - ah, thanks for that clarification on MSDAORA and age.  If I follow your question(?) the db charset is UTF8. So far, so good....