# International character in my SQL Server database does not display on my Classic ASP page

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have an international character that shows up in my SQL Server database. When I attempt to display that field on a webpage using Classic ASP, it shows up as a diamond with question mark inside. From my searching, this seems to do with UTF-8 encoding. I have added a META tag to include UTF-8 and that did not work. Below is a screenshot of how the data looks inside my SQL Server Database using the Management Studio, Query. How can I get this to display properly on my webpage?

```
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
```

[image: international character]

Comment: Try `Response.Charset = "utf-8"` in the beginning .asp file

Comment: Tks. Just tried and it does not work.  :(

Comment: Not like this hasn't been covered numerous times before - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21914278/692942

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this whole code is what it took to do the trick. It had to be at the top of my page:

```
 <%
 Session.CodePage = 65001
 Response.charset ="utf-8"
 Session.LCID     = 1033 'en-US

 %>
```

Comment: You can also use `Response.CodePage`

Comment: Using [`Session.CodePage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525649%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) *(See remarks section)* is dangerous if you haven't made sure that **all** the web applications ASP pages have been saved as `UTF-8` *(in this case)*. Basically your telling IIS to interpret all response as `UTF-8` which also means that all pages have to be saved as `UTF-8` for this to work correctly.

Comment: As [@John mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646967/international-character-in-my-sql-server-database-does-not-display-on-my-classic#comment49387706_30653030) `Response.CodePage` is better as you only affect the current page not the whole application. Just remember the page is saved as `UTF-8` when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the first line of the ASP page to include `CodePage`:

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" CodePage="65001" %>
```

`CodePage="65001"` means UTF-8.

Comment: Is that all? I guess you're assuming the OP knows to make sure the source file matches the `CodePage` directive? Admittedly most editors will default to `UTF-8` now but that's a pretty big assumption.