# Special Chars rendering on browser

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, asp-classic, character-encoding

Have situation where some special characters(such as ô) in IE8 renders properly and in IE 11 and google chrome those render as ��

Have another page where it working fine, please help me out how to identify and fix it.

Any help on that will we be highly appreciable!!

Comment: What charset/code page are you using?

Comment: Yet another encoding question. Never get sick of those! Here's an idea search Google, SO or even Google using `site:stackoverflow.com` for `+"Classic ASP"+"encoding"` and see how many questions / answers come back.

Comment: The fact it renders correctly in IE is not a good sign, because IE can easily mix up encodings because the auto detect can be overridden and the wrong setting can be stored. If it doesn't work in Chrome / Firefox that is a better measure of that it's just plain wrong.

Comment: Because I'm feeling generous - [Read this and follow the steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21914278/692942)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Attention is drawn to the Response.Charset the page and also the file. Use UTF-8.

Comment: If you are going to leave an answer *(even though its already given in the comments)* at least make it half decent and comprehensible.