# Best code page to use for spanish in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, multiple-languages

I am doing a site in spanish but the spanish grammar is not showing up correctly.

I am using UTF8

and my code is

```
<% Session.CodePage = 65001
Response.charset ="utf-8"
Session.LCID     = 1033 'en-US
Response.CodePage = 65001
%>
```

What  is the best codepage for spanish?  (Site is also in English so I thought UTF8 would be best?
What's the trick to get the spanish grammar to show correctly?

Comment: And how is the physical ASP file encoded when saved? If its not UTF-8 all that is pointless as you'll just end up with a huge encoding mismatch mess. Some [food for thought](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21914278/692942)

Comment: actually the data is saved in a database  - and then retrieved with a different asp page with the same values

Comment: Do you realise how difficult it is to debug issues when the code is stored in a database? ... You will do shortly!

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure they mean their code is stored in the database I think they are trying to pull data from a database into an ASP page and making the classic for pars when it comes to encoding.

Comment: @user2236678 To clarify you understood what I was asking, is your ASP page *(the file on your web server)* saved as UTF-8 not the data you pull from the database I'm just asking if the actual web page code is saved as UTF-8 first off. Also have you looked at the link I provided?

Comment: how do I know if the asp page is utf-8

Comment: sorry I code in visual studio - do in need to save it differently?

Comment: If you use VS try enabling the "Advanced Save Options" menu command by selecting it from the "Customise" dialog screen which you can access by right clicking on the menu bar or toolbar and selecting "Customise".

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer your question in the comments (*how do I know if the asp page is utf-8*), if you do need to save the file in a different format:

[image]

Select the **Save with encoding** option from the **Save As** dialog box.

Comment: This as well, I didn't realise until recently you could do this. I used to have to go digging in the menu customisation to find the "Advanced Save Options" dialog. +1