# Denoted parameter in stored procedure (asp)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I have a Stored Procedure here:

```
USE [RK]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[PRC_THEKE_FRAGE_INSERT]    Script Date: 03/09/2017 17:43:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_THEKE_FRAGE_INSERT] @frage nvarchar(255),@status bit, @kategorieID tinyint, @sgi nvarchar(8)
AS

-- Neuen Datensatz speichern
INSERT INTO LLThekeFragen SELECT @frage, @status, @kategorieId, @sgi
```

This procedure works fine, unless I have umlauts in my data. Then it is messing up the input. For instance, it looks like this after the insert:

> BegrÃ¼ÃŸung

This is obviously wrong. I tried to check the [MSDN-Page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7720e7dd-e370-41b2-bc08-8e192a1725ce/sql-collation-german-characters-do-not-show-up-correctly?forum=sqldatabaseengine) here, which in fact describes the problem. However, not in a stored procedure. I also tried to add `N'` to my variables, but that obviously lead to having a string (instead of the actual value).

My current charset for the table is: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

I tried changing the type for **frage** to varchar(255), which didn't help, removed the `N'`
 again.. but nothing did the trick. While checking the data in my browser, the SQL-statement is correct. It mus be while inserting it.

This is how I try to insert my data in `asp-classic`

```
SQL = "EXEC PRC_THEKE_FRAGE_INSERT '" & request("question") & "'," & request("active") & ", " & request("categoryID") & ", '" & request("sgi") & "'"
conn.execute SQL
```

(I know, not sanitizing right now and I shouldn't do this. Please don't tell that now  :) )

**Update**

Header in my actual asp-file:

```
Very first line of my code:
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001" %>

in my <head>-area:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

File with my stored procedure:

```
'this indeed did the trick - had it in the wrong file
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001" %>

<%
dim conn,SQL
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'open DB connection
conn.open "DSN=well;UID=rk;PWD=wellwell"

SQL = "EXEC PRC_THEKE_FRAGE_INSERT N'" & request("question") & "'," & request("active") & ", " & request("categoryID") & ", '" & request("sgi") & "'"
conn.execute SQL

conn.close()

%>
```

Comment: what's frage datatype in LLThekeFragen? if it's not nvarchar, then your it'll never display correctly.

Comment: This has been answered before, just search on asp-classic and utf-8 should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that to include this the very top of your page.

```
<%@Language="VBScript" CodePage = 65001 %>
<% 
  Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
  Response.CodePage = 65001
%>
```

or use an include file as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21914278/2333499

---

Use a parameterized query with `adVarWChar` parameters

 or open yourself up to [**sql-injection**](http://bobby-tables.com/) and just add `N` before your concatenating your strings.

```
SQL = "EXEC PRC_THEKE_FRAGE_INSERT N'" & request("question") & "'," & request("active") & ", " & request("categoryID") & ", N'" & request("sgi") & "'"
conn.execute SQL
```

Comment: I'll doing that in asp. wait, I'll show you how I'm calling that

Comment: @DasSaffe Are you using `SqlDbType.NVarChar` for your parameter type?

Comment: isn't that SqlDbType.NVarChar here?
`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_THEKE_FRAGE_INSERT] @frage nvarchar(255)`
sorry, new to T-SQL + Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @DasSaffe Okay, well, do the thing that you told us not to tell you to do.

Comment: I can't see how that helps in this particular situation. But ofc you are right, this will be added sooner or later. But it doesn't help if I can't insert my data correctly, even though they are safe then

Comment: Tried all of that, still not working, I'll update the question with the current suggestions you made

Comment: Nvm @SqlZim, you were right. Had the codepage in the wrong file. Works as expected. thank you

Comment: No don't use `N'` use a parameterised query.

Comment: @DasSaffe after all that you were just missing the codepage declaration in the correct file. Don't prefix with `N'` use parameterised queries by utilising the `ADODB.Command` object. Don't use `<meta>` tags in HTML to set content type, make sure you are returning UTF-8 from the server by specifying `Response.Charset = "UTF-8"` and making sure your ASP file is saved as UTF-8 and with the `<%@codepage=65001%>` directive it is processed by ASP as UTF-8. The advice so far in this answer is poor to say the least.

Comment: Also `SqlDbType.NVarChar` is the ADO.Net data type for `NVARCHAR` so no idea why this is mentioned here the equivalent in ADODB is the constant `adVarWChar`.

Comment: @Lankymart OP said they would be switching to parameterized queries later. I mentioned `SqlDbType.NVarChar` because OP hadn't said they were using classic asp yet. The original question didn't even specify this was an issue originating from an application. Please look at the revisions made to the question before throwing me under the bus.

Comment: @SqlZim wasn't *"throwing you under a bus"*, if revisions have been made update the answer, because the "For asp classic" section isn't great.

Comment: @Lankymart If you want to edit my answer to improve it, or post your own, please feel free. Your understanding of asp classic is much better than mine.

Comment: I've already written about this before, I'd just be repeating myself.