# How to select from table where table is including åäö characters?

Tags: mysql, sql, vbscript, character-encoding, asp-classic

I have set my mysql database, tables and columns to be charset utf8mb4.
I have set the .asp page to have Response.charset="utf-8"

How do write a select where I check if the rs is including åäö characters?

If I use the below and the variable is without åäö then it works, but if the variable contains a word with åäö, then it doesn´t find it!

```
thepassword="trött"
sql = "SELECT * FROM table where  password = '"& thepassword &"' ;" 
set rs = conn.Execute (sql)
```

Any input really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Using parameterized queries might help you with that as the SQL engine takes care of escaping certain characters and properly preparing the query for you. See: [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/542542)

Comment: There are other steps you need to check not just setting `Response.Charset = "UTF-8"`, here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21914278/692942) that should help.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working in the end :-)