# Convert ANSI varchars to Unicode nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, unicode, varchar, nvarchar

Due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/920405/2662901) I have a table full of `varchar` values (e.g., `æˆ¦è‰¦å¸å›½`) that I need to convert to proper unicode `nvarchar` values (e.g.,`戦艦帝国`).  How can I do that within T-SQL?

Comment: I doubt that's possible unless someone painstakingly wrote some app to do it.  There's just no mapping (I'm assuming)...how could there be?  Who keeps it up to date?

Comment: @rory.ap - Perhaps I need to include this detail: the values were originally from inserted to the DB with ASP code running with an IIS CodePage = 936.  Somehow that ASP is magically able to get them back out of the database and into their original unicode majesty as long as the CodePage and CharSet aren't touched....

Comment: If it's a UTF-8 encoding, it may be possible... but you'd need to do it in C# code and not in SQL. You'd add the nvarchar() column, then run a utility that reads the UTF-8 encoded string, and then writes out a UTF-16 encoded unicode string to the new column. After you're done, you could drop (and rename?) the new column. The C# text stream reader & writer classes have the option to specify encodings for just such translations.